# Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\DoctorController::edit()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

Hey I am making a edit page for user to edit the information but I am getting this error.

**Code of controller is:**

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $doctor = Doctor::find($id);
    // Redirect to state list if updating state wasn't existed
    if ($doctor == null || count($doctor) == 0) {
        return redirect()->intended('doctor/doctorList');
    }
    return view('doctor/doctorEdit', ['doctor' => $doctor]);
}
```

**My route is:**

```
Route::get('doctor/doctorEdit/edit','DoctorController@edit')->name('doctor.edit');
```

**My view is:**

```
   <a href="{{ route('doctor.edit', ['id' => $doctor->id]) }}" class="btn btn-warning col-sm-3 col-xs-5 btn-margin" style="width:100px; margin-left:20px;">
                    Update
                    </a>
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: <a href="{{ route('doctor.edit', $doctor->id) }}"...

Comment: @LeonardoCabré still giving the same error

Comment: You can switch back to your original route. You can pass either an array **or** a string/int.

Answer (score 3):

Because your controller method is accepting a parameter, your route needs to have a parameter in it.

`Route::get('doctor/{doctor}/edit','DoctorController@edit')->name('doctor.edit');`

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing a wildcard (parameter) in your route file.

Change your route, to match a primary key that relates to the specific doctor, it can be a username or simply an id.

```
 Route::get('doctor/{id}/doctorEdit/edit','DoctorController@edit')->name('doctor.edit');
```

Make sure you are passing the wildcard appropriately based on your directory

And use that wildcard in your controller

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $doctor = Doctor::where('id', $id)->first();
    // Redirect to state list if updating state wasn't existed
    if ($doctor == null || count($doctor) == 0) {
        return redirect()->intended('doctor/doctorList');
    }
    return view('doctor/doctorEdit', ['doctor' => $doctor]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your route doesnt have parameter so change your route.

from this.

```
Route::get('doctor/doctorEdit/edit','DoctorController@edit')->name('doctor.edit');
```

to this

```
Route::get('doctor/doctorEdit/edit/{id}','DoctorController@edit')->name('doctor.edit');
```

or maybe u want the same method to post

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'doctor/doctorEdit/edit/{id}','DoctorController@edit')->name('doctor.edit');
```